# Unrecognized Instance sent to - Delegates

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiview, cocos2d-iphone, delegates

I created a static library for use in my other iOS application projects. The way it works is the application project implements the protocol in my static library and calls a method in the static library. Then the static library presents a view on top of the calling view. Here's how the code is:

MyFile.h file of the main class in delegate:

```
@protocol MyHandlerDelegate <NSObject>

     - (void)infoRetrieved:(BOOL)success;

@end

@interface MyFile : UIViewController
{
    id <MyHandlerDelegate> delegate;
}

@property (retain) id delegate;
```

MyFile.m contains:

```
- (void)showRewards
{
    [[[self delegate] view] addSubview:view1];
}
```

Now when I created a dummy application with just a single button, this worked fine and the static library successfully presented a view on top of the calling view.
Now I need to make this work in an open source game TweetJump (built on Cocos2D). In the highscores class, I have included the header file and implemented the delegate. In the implementation file, I call the following code:

```
MyFile *mf = [[MyFile alloc] init];
[mf setDelegate:self];
[mf showRewards];
```

For your consideration, I have hosted the Highscore class - [Header](https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/90817764/Highscores.h) and [Implementation](https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/90817764/Highscores.m). The error that I am getting when the above method is executed is:

`2013-04-16 23:54:42.658 tweejump[11502:c07] +[Highscore view]: unrecognized selector sent to class 0xecc08
2013-04-16 23:54:42.661 tweejump[11502:c07] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '+[Highscore view]: unrecognized selector sent to class 0xecc08'`

I know its a tedious question. Will greatly appreciate the help. Thanks

Comment: Your Highscore class is missing the view property, which ought to return a UIView* object for addSubview to work.

Comment: So where do you reckon I place that method in highscore file? Thanks

Comment: Anywhere, it just needs to be there and return the Highscore's UIView* object (the one which you want to add the "view1" object to). It should probably be a property.

Comment: Sorry I didn't get you. Could you refer to a point in the link where I should add it.

Comment: You add a @property to the Highscore class. It doesn't matter where.

Answer (score 1):

It's telling you that Highscore class does not have a view method. You protocol says the delegate only has to be an NSObject nothing more specific.

Comment: The game's main class calles the highscore class that presents the highscore and stuff to the user on the view. That is why I am trying to call the method there so that my view can come on top of that view..Where do you reckon I should place that...Currently, I am calling it in initWithHighScore: method in the implementation link above..

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you're calling this code in a class method rather than an instance method. An object is not interchangeable with its class. Have your actual Highscore object do this instead of the class.

Comment: Currently, I am calling it in initWithHighScore: method in the implementation link above..

Comment: @GauravWadhwani: It isn't in the code you linked. Did you maybe link the wrong thing?